# Subdirectories for countries, but no content in the root level - a problem?

Tags: subdirectory, site-structure

We are in New Zealand and operate in NZ and Australia. We have a .com domain with /nz and /au subdirectories. All content is in the subdirectories and the root level only has a splash page to select either NZ or Aus. Is this a problem?

One "expert" says no, another that we lose ranking traction by having content below the expected level(s). From what I've read, using directories is an appropriate structure, but I can't find any discussion of having a "blank" root level, and I'm not sure if this is common or highly unusual. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like may websites where the content is in different languages- no different really in your case. You should have a bit of a home page and some common content so that your home page ranks on it's own. The reason for this is simple. People will check out your home page even when they get to your site and found what they needed. It should cover who you are and what you do. I can be brief. Just make sure that it is substantial enough to meet expectations. And that is the point. It is not only important to follow some tradition, but to meet the expectations of your users. That is number one in my book!

Your one expert is not such an expert I suspect. At one point, Google and other search engines considered levels in a directory hierarchy as an indicator of importance just as the number of clicks it takes getting from the home page to any other page. Conceptually, this still exists and one reason why I recommend making a relatively flat hierarchy structure. However, you have to create for your site makes sense. Make it for people. For this reason, if it makes sense to have /nz and /au as a major factor in your structure, then do it. But do not duplicate content without using a canonical tag from one to another. Just know that structure depth, while important, is not as critical as it appears your expert made it. Just do not get carried away. It is all about common sense.

But do make sure you have a home page. Please. Do not leave a blank directory or a relatively blank page. It does not have to say much, but make it say something. You will find that your home page is the most visited page for a reason. People are curious. As well, search engines expect it so don't disappoint them either.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using a canonical tag between the AU and NZ pages, implementing that would mean one of the areas of the site would not be indexed in Google.  Using hreflang would be the correct solution: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

Comment: @Max You are right of course! I guess I did not specifically mean from /nz to /au, but I realize that is how it reads. Ooopppsss!!! I just meant from one page to another- duplicate to original. Sorry for the confusion. I appreciate the clarification. It is definitely good that you chimed in for the OP. Thanks!! Also, I was assuming that Australia and New Zealand were English. ;-) But you are also right about hreflang. Did not think about that necessarily. I was just thinking about structure, depth, and the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I recommend in your case.

Put Australian content in the /au folder and New Zealand content in /nz folder including the default index pages.

Then in your document root, make a script to detect the country the client is from using an accept-language HTTP header then based on the returned language code, redirect the user to the correct page.

Here's a PHP sample I quickly created to get you started. You'll have to adjust some text, particularly the text after "Location" to match to your country specific URLs.

```
<?php
    $language=strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
    if (strpos($language,"nz") > -1){
    // found nz for New Zealand
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Redirect",true);
    header("Location: http://example.com/path/to/nz",true);
    exit();
    }
    if (strpos($language,"au") > -1){
    // found au for Australia
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Redirect",true);
    header("Location: http://example.com/path/to/au",true);
    exit();
    }
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Redirect",true);
    header("Location: http://example.com/path/to/other-countries",true);
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: Although not incorrect, I'd recommend against using an automated redirect based on a users perceived location. Even though I'm based in NZ, I might want to see the AU pages.  I think a landing page for the root with a country selector might be better.

Comment: Can you instead have an link on each country page that takes you to the country selection screen? It will be much better for the users who don't want to take the time to choose a country.

Comment: Yeah that could be an option, give them clear path back to it. Although with this code, what would happen when Google Bot hits the root page?